# Issue with initCoreNLP() in the coreNLP r package - the process never ends

Tags: r, stanford-nlp

I have downloaded and installed the coreNLP package in R.

Before that, I had downloaded CoreNLP tool suite separately.

I want to run these tools through R and I did it as follows.

```
library(coreNLP)

annotators<-c("tokenize","ssplit","pos","lemma","ner","parse","dcoref")

setwd("C://Nikhil//stanford-corenlp")

initCoreNLP(getwd(), mem = "2g", annotators)
```

When I give this command, there is no error but the process does NOT END. The cursor merely spins round and round endlessly. What could be the reason and how to overcome this? thanks.